# With Python Logging and a curly brace style, how to format an additional LogRecord attribute containing a datetime?

Tags: python, python-logging

I added a 'time' attribute to logRecord that contains a datetime.
I want to format this new attribute to display only the hours for example

I tried this :

```
import logging
import datetime

class MyLogRecord(logging.LogRecord):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) : 
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.time = datetime.datetime.now()

logging.setLogRecordFactory(MyLogRecord)

logging.basicConfig( format="%(time)s %(message)s")
logging.debug("benoit lecuppe")

logging.basicConfig(style='{', format="{time:%H} {message}",force=True)
logging.debug("benoit lecuppe")
```

and an exception occurs;

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
invalid format: bad specifier: '%H'
ValueError: bad specifier: '%H'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "D:\repos\nexo-binance\pynescript\test5.py", line 14, in <module>
    logging.basicConfig(style='{', format="{time:%H} {message}",force=True)
ValueError: invalid format: bad specifier: '%H'
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Why did you put `:%H` there? What did you expect that to do?

Comment: I expect to display only hours like with str.format :
'''
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
print( str.format("t={dt:%H}",dt=dt))
'''

Comment: Huh. `datetime.datetime` implements `__format__` as `strftime`. I didn't know that. Looks like the exception is coming from an over-aggressive [format validator](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.3/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L469) in the `logging` code that rejects unusual format specs even if the type responsible for `__format__` would actually be fine with it.

Comment: search "bad specifier" in [link](Lib/logging/__init__.py) suggest that exception was emited by method Validate of class StrFormatStyle.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is due to `logging.Formatter()`
This formater can use a datetime format string but can't validate it.
That's normal because a datetime format string can contain anything.
There is a parameter name `validate` in `Loggin.formatter` constructor but `logging.basicConfig` cannot permit to set the parameter.

```
import datetime

class MyLogRecord(logging.LogRecord):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) : 
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.time = datetime.datetime.now()

logging.setLogRecordFactory(MyLogRecord)

    
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(validate=False, style='{', fmt="{time:%H %m} {message}"))
rootLog = logging.getLogger()
rootLog.addHandler(handler)
rootLog.level = logging.DEBUG

#logging.basicConfig(style='{', format="{time} {message}" ,handlers=[handler], force=True)

logging.debug("benoit lecuppe")
```

Answer (score 0):

An other way is to `override logging.basicConfig()` like that :

```
import logging
import datetime

class MyLogRecord(logging.LogRecord):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) : 
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.time = datetime.datetime.now()

logging.setLogRecordFactory(MyLogRecord)

oldBasicConfig = logging.basicConfig
def newbasicConfig(**kwargs):
    if  kwargs.pop("validate", True) == True :
        logging.basicConfig(**kwargs) 
    else :
        style = kwargs.get("style", '%')
        default = logging._STYLES[style][1]
        format = kwargs.pop("format", default)

        oldBasicConfig(format= default,**kwargs)
        dfs = kwargs.pop("datefmt", None)
        fmt = logging.Formatter(format, dfs, style,validate=False)
        root =  logging.getLogger()
        for h in root.handlers: h.setFormatter(fmt)
logging.basicConfig = newbasicConfig
```

the result is :

```
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, style='{', format="{time:%H %m} {message}", force=True, validate=False)
    
>>> logging.debug("benoit lecuppe")
08 05 benoit lecuppe
```